# clojure: (apply fn coll) vs (apply #(apply fn %&) coll)

Tags: clojure

I am working my way through labrepl and I saw some code that follows this pattern:

```
;; Pattern
(apply #(apply f %&) coll)

;; Concrete example
user=> (apply #(apply + %&) [1 2 3 4])
10
```

This seems to be equivalent to this pattern:

```
;; Pattern
(apply f coll)

;; Concrete example
user=> (apply + [1 2 3 4]) 
10
```

Are these patterns equivalent? If not, what's the difference and when would you use one over the other?

I took the former pattern from the [step function](https://github.com/relevance/labrepl/blob/master/src/solutions/automaton.clj#L54) in the cellular-automata lab of labrepl:

```
(defn step
  "Advance the automation by one step, updating all cells."
  [board]
  (doall
   (map (fn [window]
          (apply #(apply map brians-brain-rules %&)
                 (doall (map torus-window window))))
        (torus-window board))))
```

**Update:** I added a concrete example of each pattern to help make the question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference. There is no reason to write the longer form; I can only assume it was arrived at by gradual changes to code that made sense at one time.

Comment: Agreed. I thought maybe the parameter might make a difference, but `(apply #(apply (fn [c] (map + c [1 1 1])) %&) [[-1 -1 -1]])` and `(apply (fn [c] (map + c [1 1 1])) [[-1 -1 -1]])` were equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, both forms accomplish the same thing and are more or less the same. Each provides a way to introduce an anonymous function.

Using `#(...` is a Clojure reader shorthand for an anonymous function. It is kind of equivalent to `(fn [arg1 & args]...` , but you cannot embed one `#(...` anonymous function inside another, and arguments are expressed as `% %2...` or `%1 %2...` rather than with vector binding `(fn [arg & args]`.

Both are methods to express an anonymous function. `#(...` is used for simpler functions, and `(fn...` is used for more detailed functions.

`#(...` tends to make things look a little neater.

Comment: No...why the two apply functions?

Comment: My question isn't about the different syntaxes for anonymous functions. I added examples to my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @rigdern using `fn` to represent any funcion is misleading, i edited the question